# s attribute vs L attribute grammar during evaluation of parse tree

Tags: compiler-construction

What kind of problem can occur in evaluation of parse tree attributes if the grammar is neither S attributed nor L attributed ?

Answer (score 0):

S- and L-attributed grammars are particularly simple to deal with in that, for example, attribute evaluation can be performed directly along top-down parsing. (Only S-attributed grammars are easy with bottom-up parsing.)
Once we use more general attribute grammars, the attribute grammar system must do more housekeeping as in maintaining the CST with attributes explicitly and performing a dependency analysis upfront to perform attribute evaluation past parsing.

Additionally, a parser generator (such as ANTLR 3) could use attribute for semantic disambiguation. Clearly, the corresponding attributes would need to be available just in time when a (top-down) parser would attempt a rule. This would work for L-attributed grammars, but not for general AGs.